google form quiz checkboxes not offering multiple options, just correct or incorrect
I built a google forms quiz and used checkboxes for 30 questions that each have six possible responses. It seems I can't score each with a point value - it only gives me the option of scoring correct or incorrect. I want to assign a point value to each response and have it tally the responses at the end to score a respondent according to my rubric.
I have tried to multiple choices and was told to try checkboxes for more flexibility. I'm workign with an idea that is not about correct or incorrect. Instead, I want to create a value for each response but can ony score one point per question. How do I allow different points to score each of the possible six responses please?
This works fine when one option is selected, however I am unable to get it to send multiple selections.
Thanks in advance!

I have tried to multiple choices and was told to try checkboxes for more flexibility. What was the source of this advice? How do I allow different points to score each of the possible six responses please? Multiple choice is the convention so it's difficult to visualise a checkbox equivalent. Would you please edit the question to include an example of a checkbox question and answers and the marking rubric. Results Please advise whether you want to release the results "Immediately" or "Later"? FWIW, if the latter, then a script could easily calculate the 'checkbox" score.
